# Strapi on aws refusing connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, strapi

I have set up strapi instance on aws according to [this guide](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/deployment/amazon-aws.html). I followed all steps and set up my security group correctly, but for some reason, my ec2 instance refuses connections on port 80, 443 **and** 1337

Anyone got an idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out. It turns out this wasn’t a problem with AWS or Strapi at all.

I had messed up the database security settings, so each time the strapi process tried to start, the database refused the connection (I hadn‘t set it up with the right security group) and strapi failed to start. `PM2` silently captured this and tried to start strapi again, resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: Same happened to me. More specifically, the database SG's inbound rule provided a very specific source, i.e. the initial IP of my EC2 instance.

Since I restart it often, I've changed the source to the EC2's own SG, which solves the problem.